# Generating a dataframe from a list of arrays and a list?

Tags: arrays, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have the following list and list of numpy arrays:

```
x = [np.array([5.50000002, 6.69999989]),
 np.array([4.83736559, 7.        ]),
 np.array([0.44784402, 1.49999997, 4.18910619]),
 np.array([0.1       , 2.30000004, 3.30995852])]

y = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I would like to generate a pandas dataframe of the following format:

```
df = 
x          y
5.50000002 2
6.69999989 2
4.83736559 3
7          3
0.44784402 4
1.49999997 4
4.18910619 4
0.1        5
2.30000004 5
3.30995852 5
```

What is the fastest way to do this when I can expect x and y to be very large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `explode`

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y}).explode('x')
Out[17]: 
          x  y
0       5.5  2
0       6.7  2
1   4.83737  3
1         7  3
2  0.447844  4
2       1.5  4
2   4.18911  4
3       0.1  5
3       2.3  5
3   3.30996  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `concatenate` and `repeat`:

```
pd.DataFrame({'x':np.concatenate(x), 
              'y':np.repeat(y,[len(a) for a in x])})
```

Output:

```
          x  y
0  5.500000  2
1  6.700000  2
2  4.837366  3
3  7.000000  3
4  0.447844  4
5  1.500000  4
6  4.189106  4
7  0.100000  5
8  2.300000  5
9  3.309959  5
```